# Capstone ethereum

Tags: ethereum, capstone, evm

According to the [capstone repository](https://github.com/aquynh/capstone), the support for Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) bytecode was added. However, I cannot figure out, how to use capstone for EVM, neither with Java nor with python bindings (I tried only these two languages). The respective documentations [java](https://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_java.html) and [python](https://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_python.html) do not refer to the bytecode of the EVM.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not familiar with capstone, but presumably the `CODE` variable referenced in the python version of the docs is where you would put the bytecode. What did you try, and what result did you get?

Comment: Hi, I filed an issue on the github repository and the owner replies by giving me an example in C: `https://github.com/aquynh/capstone/blob/master/tests/test_evm.c`. Now I will try and let you know.

Comment: You have a python exemple at : https://github.com/aquynh/capstone/blob/master/bindings/python/test_evm.py
But I had an issue with this exemple, the bytecode string should be prepended with 'b'.
So "\x60\x61\x55" becomes b"\x60\x61\x55" and the code isn't crashing anymore.